# The link to start webpay not loaded from Azure web application

Tags: web-services, azure, payment-gateway

We use Azure for our webapp FoodIF, and in the process of integration with WEBPAY (Chilean Paypal), the link to start the payment procces dont work from Azure, but work properly from other server.

Specifically, from the server where is the app we can not connect to the webservice link of [WEBPAY](https://tbk.orangepeople.cl/WSWebpayTransaction/cxf/WSWebpayService?wsdl), which is used to start the process payment through Webpay.

Throws this error:

> invoke-webrRequest was aborted: The request was aborted: Could not
>   create SSL/TLS secure

How could I solve this problem?